# How can I know longitude and latitude points?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I know longitude and latitude points? and In my case
A dialog appears every time the GPS is deactivated. How can I stop this after locating?

[This is dialog appears every time the GPS is deactivated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tig9b.jpg)
..................................................................................................................................................................

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static final int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID = 3;

    private static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED";

    private TextView gps_status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gps_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gps_status);
        initGoogleAPIClient();//Init Google API Client
        checkPermissions();//Check Permission
    }

    /* Initiate Google API Client  */
    private void initGoogleAPIClient() {
        //Without Google API Client Auto Location Dialog will not work
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /* Check Location Permission for Marshmallow Devices */
    private void checkPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                requestLocationPermission();
            else
                showSettingDialog();
        } else
            showSettingDialog();

    }

    /*  Show Popup to access User Permission  */
    private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID);
        }
    }

    /* Show Location Access Dialog */
    private void showSettingDialog() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);//Setting priotity of Location request to high
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);//5 sec Time interval for location update
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient to show dialog always when GPS is off

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case RESULT_OK:
                        Log.e("Settings", "Result OK");
                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                        //startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.e("Settings", "Result Cancel");
                        updateGPSStatus("GPS is Disabled in your device");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver, new IntentFilter(BROADCAST_ACTION));//Register broadcast receiver to check the status of GPS
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Unregister receiver on destroy
        if (gpsLocationReceiver != null)
            unregisterReceiver(gpsLocationReceiver);
    }

    //Run on UI
    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showSettingDialog();
        }
    };

    /* Broadcast receiver to check status of GPS */
    private BroadcastReceiver gpsLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //If Action is Location
            if (intent.getAction().matches(BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                //Check if GPS is turned ON or OFF
                if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    Log.e("About GPS", "GPS is Enabled in your device");
                    updateGPSStatus("GPS is Enabled in your device");
                } else {
                    //If GPS turned OFF show Location Dialog
                    new Handler().postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 10);
                    // showSettingDialog();
                    updateGPSStatus("GPS is Disabled in your device");
                    Log.e("About GPS", "GPS is Disabled in your device");
                }

            }
        }
    };

    //Method to update GPS status text
    private void updateGPSStatus(String status) {
        gps_status.setText(status);
    }


    /* On Request permission method to check the permisison is granted or not for Marshmallow+ Devices  */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION_INTENT_ID: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //If permission granted show location dialog if APIClient is not null
                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        initGoogleAPIClient();
                        showSettingDialog();
                    } else
                        showSettingDialog();


                } else {
                    updateGPSStatus("Location Permission denied.");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location Permission denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```